# CodeCeption - can you use a if statement inside acceptance test?

Tags: php, codeception

Here is a snippet of the code for my acceptance test:

```
$value= $I->grabFromDatabase('table', 'Settingcolumn', array('userid' => '1'));

if ($value="Y")

{
$I->see('hello world');

}

elseif ($value="N")

{
$I->dontSee('hello world');

}
```

Is an if/else statement in codeception possible? I currently have the setting value=N so hello world is hidden on the web page, but  CodeCeption is skipping the if/else, going right to " $I->see('hello world');" and failing right because it does not see hello world. 
    * I see "hello world"
    FAIL

Comment: Codeception does not skip IFs, you have made a mistake, you should use comparison operator ``==`` instead of assignement ``=``

Comment: An interesting question would be if one could do stuff like `if ($I->see("this")) { $I->click("this"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure you can it's a PHP file at last and Codeception executes the whole file.